# Executing a Scala code file with the intepreter

Tags: scala

Here is my sample source code:

```
// Broken.scala
def fibFrom(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] = a #:: fibFrom(b, a + b)
println(fibFrom(0,1).take(10).toList)
```

When I run these statements individually in the interpreter, everything works fine.

```
scala> def fibFrom(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] = a #:: fibFrom(b, a + b)
fibFrom: (a: Int, b: Int)Stream[Int]

scala> println(fibFrom(0,1).take(10).toList)
List(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34)
```

However, when I pass the file itself to the interpreter, it hangs.

```
$ scala Broken.scala
^C
$
```

The `scala -help` documentation indicates that Scala source is a valid input to `scala`, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's trying very gently to tell you that you used a semicolon… ;)

Comment: Hahah - Not sure if serious or not, but I removed the semicolon and it behaves the same.

Comment: I broke my "no emoticons" policy for nothing! See my answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me. I think you may be encountering a problem with the `scala` command trying to start the background compiler, which is how Scala scripts are handled.

This is a problem that happens on certain OSes or with certain security software / settings. From [1]:

> There are two things you may want to look at. First, `hostname` must
>   resolve to your host's IP address -- even if it's 127.0.0.1. Second, there
>   may be an fsc daemon running causing the trouble. Try running fsc -shutdown.

[1] http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-user/12bkn165h9/cannot-execute-hello-world-script

Comment: Those workarounds seem a bit severe to me, but further down the page I found a better solution: `scala -nc <file>`

Comment: I think you'll find that pretty slow. The nice thing about the default is that it only compiles the source if it has changed since the last time you ran it. Furthermore, but keeping the compiler running in the background, its own start-up overhead is incurred only once and even more it gets fully JIT-compiled.